# I need to join two objects in Angular and Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to join two lists of objects in one.
The first list is of the movies that I created.
The second list is of the movies that have shared me.
I want to join those two lists so that they mix and order alphabetically, since right now they are separated.

[image]

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {compartir_con: "", descripcion: "", id: "", link_descarga: "", portada: "", …}
1: {compartir_con: "", descripcion: "", id: "", link_descarga: "", portada: "", …}
2: {compartir_con: "", descripcion: "", id: "", link_descarga: "", portada: "", …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
list-films.component.ts:68
```

```
[{…}]
0: {compartir_con: "", descripcion: "", id: "", link_descarga: "", portada: "", …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

In the html for my films:

```
<div *ngFor="let film of (films | orderBy: ['+vista','+titulo'] ) | grdFilter: {titulo: searchText, descripcion: searchText};">
```

In the html for shared films:

```
<div *ngFor="let film of (shared | orderBy: ['+vista','+titulo'] ) | grdFilter: {titulo: searchText, descripcion: searchText};">
```

This is my data-api.service.ts

```
getAllYourFilms(id) {
  this.filmsCollection = this.afs.collection('films', ref => 
    ref.where('userUid', '==', id));
    return this.films = this.filmsCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(changes => {
        return changes.map(action => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as FilmInterface;
          data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
        });
      }));
  }
getAllFilmsSharedWithYou(email) {
  this.filmsCollection = this.afs.collection('films', ref => 
    ref.where('compartir_con', '==', email));
    return this.films = this.filmsCollection.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(changes => {
        return changes.map(action => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as FilmInterface;
          data.id = action.payload.doc.id;
          return data;
      });
  }));
}
```

My list-films.component.ts

```
getListFilms(iduser) {
    this.dataApi.getAllYourFilms(iduser)
      .subscribe(films => {
        this.films = films;
        console.log(films);
     });
  }

  getListFilmsShared(email) {
      this.dataApi.getAllFilmsSharedWithYou(email)
          .subscribe(films => {
            this.shared = films;
        console.log(films);
          });
  }
```

I need all the movies in the same array.

```
[0]{…}
[1]{…}
[2]{…}
[3]{…}
```

But actually is:

My films

```
[0]{…}
[1]{…}
[2]{…}
```

Shared with me

```
[0]{…}
```

**Sollution**

I edit this function (list-films.component.ts):

```
getListFilmsShared(email) {
   this.dataApi.getAllFilmsSharedWithYou(email)
     .subscribe(films => {
        this.films = this.films.concat(films);
     });
}
```

Comment: have you tried the answer?

Comment: @PeterHaddad I am trying to make the changes that you have indicated in data-api.service.ts, I get the following error: "error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable<FilmInterface>'"

Comment: @PeterHaddad Hello, I have solved my problem by changing the function getListFilmsShared with: this.films = this.films.concat(films); Thanks for your help and patience.